# Which page to make isThreadSafe=false in jsp

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

I am working with a database project developed using JSP,servlet. It is an ERP project having more than 20 users. My boss told me to use Multi-theading in project. Please tell me how to make decision of which pages should be muti-threaded and which should not.

Comment: The web container is multi-threaded, and handles multi-threading for you. Just don't store any state in servlets, and even less in JSPs (which shouldn't have any Java code anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Java multi-threading in jsp is not a valid argument as such because as @JBNizet said, a web container already handles multithreading for you.

What you can do though is use multi-threading in cases you have code that can be run asynchronously.

Lets assume you have the scenario where :

```
obj1 = obj2.getValFromDb(obj3.getSessionId(obj4.getId()));
```

In this, multi-threading cannot be used because the tasks have to be executed sequentially in order to get to the result. So a single thread is all you need...

But in the example below...

```
val = getValFromDb()+getValFromSRC1()+getValFromSRC2();
```

The sub-results can be calculated in separate threads.

So, you have to make an evaluation of your code and use multi-threading appropriately.

As for the `isThreadSafe` directive in jsps, the only thing you can do is to disable multi-threading (which is the opposite you are looking for).  As the specification says:

> The use of the SingleThreadModel interface guarantees that only one
>   thread at a time will execute in a given servlet instance’s service
>   method. It is important to note that this guarantee only applies to
>   each servlet instance, since the container may choose to pool such
>   objects. Objects that are accessible to more than one servlet instance
>   at a time, such as instances of HttpSession, may be available at any
>   particular time to multiple servlets, including those that implement
>   SingleThreadModel.